# WPF Converters DLL - Failed to Add Reference

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I´m using Kent Boogaart DLLs for WPF Converters im VS2008

http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/downloads/get/648993

When I try to import Kent.Boogaart.Converters.dll, I receive an error.

Is this release just for VS2012 ?

[image]

http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/releases/view/104331

Comment: I dont know how to visualize the error. There is no message or information. I just cant use the dll

Comment: In the download section there are 3.5,4.0 and 4.5 versions. Are you sure you referenced the correct version?

Comment: @jure, I couldn´t see any sections in download section http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/releases/view/104331. (I´m noob)

Comment: In the "other available downloads" there's a file named "WpfConverters.1.3.1.FX35..". That's a version of the library for use in .NET 3.5 assemblies. I suppose in VS 2008 you are targeting .NET 3.5 so try with that one.

Comment: here's a direct link http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/downloads/get/648991

Comment: worked fine...! thanks... I must be blind

Comment: humm... FX40 means .net 4.0..